# Generated texture coordinates with shape key

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shape-keys, coordinates

I'm having difficulty using *generated texture coordinates* with *shape keys*.

Consider a surface like this (from Wikipedia):

[image]

I'm using a material that sets the color of the surface by its z-height (i.e. the z-component of the generated texture coordinates).

I'd like to animate the field with a shape key, however it seems that the generated texture coordinates are always derived from the *basis mesh*, rather than the result of applying the shape keys.

Is there a way to get the generated texture coordinates to update when the shape key weights change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the Object texture coordinate input instead of Generated. Works for me.

[image]